# How to use GSON to deserialize <Range<Date>> object

Tags: date, gson, range, android-room, typeconverter

My problem is simple. I have to implement some TypeConverters to manage data for a Room database in Android.

I have no problem to serielize a Range< Date>> to a string for storage it. I'm using the easy way:

```
@TypeConverter
fun rangeToString(range: Range <Date>?): String {
    val gson = Gson()
    return gson.toJson(range)
}
```

But when I try to get back the same information with the reverse process:

```
@TypeConverter
fun stringToRange(value: String): Range <Date>? {
    val mapType = object: TypeToken<Range <Date>?>() {}.type
    return Gson().fromJson (value, mapType)
}
```

I'm getting an error: Unable to invoke no-args constructor for java.util.Comparator <java.util.Date>. Registering an InstanceCreator with Gson for this type may fix this problem.

I understand that the problem is GSON doesn't know how to instance a Range with Dates. I think that maybe if I use a custom registerTypeAdapter or something similar could solve the problem but I'm not finding the way.

Any idea? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Let's make it easier. I could not figure out how to deserialize a Range< Date> but I've solved it changing the object for a Pair<Date, Date>.

My new final and easy TypeConverters:

```
@TypeConverter
fun stringToRange(value: String): Pair<Date, Date>? {
    val mapType = object : TypeToken<Pair<Date, Date>?>() {}.type
    return Gson().fromJson(value, mapType)
}

@TypeConverter
fun rangeToString(range: Pair<Date, Date>?): String {
    val gson = Gson()
    return gson.toJson(range)
}
```

You can easily transform your Range< Date> doing:

```
Pair(dateRange.minimum, dateRange.maximum)
```

With this solution I'm not answering my question but this is another way to fix the problem.